# Splitting a word into two words with spaCy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, tokenize

I'm facing an issue where I need to split a single 'word' into two words due to missing spaces or new lines in the received text. My intention is to establish a pipeline (spaCy 3.5.4) for this task prior to utilizing more advanced NLP techniques.

The criteria for identifying the words to be split are as follows:

- The word should have `.is_oov` set to `True`.
- The `.shape_` of the word should be in the format of `XxxXxx` or something similar, such as having a number in front or after.

Here's an illustrative example:

```
for token in doc:
  if token.is_oov ==True:
    print (token.text, token.shape_)
    [split here...]
```

with the following output:

```
62.000Unbefristeter dd.dddXxxxx
KundenFlexible XxxxxXxxxx
WorkDiverse XxxxXxxxx
RabatteFlache XxxxxXxxxx
ArbeitsumfeldIhre XxxxxXxxx
Stellenauswahl Xxxxx
```

While the last example is a false positive, the remaining instances need to be split into two words, and it's essential to retain the text for subsequent processing.

I'm familiar with regular expressions, but I'm curious if there is a simpler approach using spaCy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with using spaCy's pipeline functionality, you can define a custom tokenizer with a regular expression (regex) that splits words as desired (I can't pre-empt all the edge cases you will encounter but the following regex is relatively robust):

```py
import re

import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer

test_str = (
    "62.000Unbefristeter KundenFlexible WorkDiverse RabatteFlache ArbeitsumfeldIhre"
    " Stellenauswahl another ANOTHER, AnnNother annOther another1 ANOTHER11, another?!"
)

# Define a regex that handles desired cases
infix_re = re.compile(r"[A-Z|a-z][a-z]+|[0-9][0-9.]+|[A-Z]+|[^\s]+")


# Define custom tokenizer that uses the regex
def custom_tokenizer(nlp_pipeline):
    return Tokenizer(nlp_pipeline.vocab, infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer)


nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")  # Load the pipeline
nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)  # Change the tokenizer
doc = nlp(test_str)  # Process
print(" ".join(tok.text for tok in doc))
```

**Output**

```
62.000 Unbefristeter Kunden Flexible Work Diverse Rabatte Flache Arbeitsumfeld Ihre Stellenauswahl another ANOTHER , Ann Nother ann Other another 1 ANOTHER 11 , another ?!
```

Alternatively, (as you alluded to in your question) you can leave the original pipeline intact and use a regex on the output tokens from spaCy's tokenisation process. You'll probably want to use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) on each `tok.text` from the `doc`.